# How to insert multiple data from html to database using laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i have this dynamic table, this is a preview of my problem: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjucJ.png)

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <h4>Estado:</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table preview-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sexo</th>
                            <th>Color</th>
                            <th>Raza</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Precio x kg</th>
                            <th>Peso</th>
                            <th>Monto</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody> <!-- preview content goes here-->
                </table>
            </div>                            
        </div>
    </div>
```

I add rows with this Jquery

```
$(function(){
var cont = 1;
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){ //Introduce los nuevos campo
    var form_data = {};
    form_data["sexo"] = $('.payment-form #sexo option:selected').text();
    form_data["color"] = $('.payment-form input[name="color"]').val();
    form_data["raza"] = $('.payment-form #raza option:selected').text();
    form_data["tipo"] = $('.payment-form #tipo option:selected').text();
    form_data["precio"] = $('.payment-form input[name="precio"]').val();
    form_data["peso"] = $('.payment-form input[name="peso"]').val();
    form_data["monto"] = parseFloat($('.payment-form input[name="precio"]').val()*$('.payment-form input[name="peso"]').val()).toFixed(2);
    form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
        $('<td class="input-'+type+'"><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="data-'+type+'" value="'+value+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
        cont++;
    });
    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row); 
    calc_total();
    $('#sexo').val('');
    $('#color').val('');
    $('#raza').val('');
    $('#tipo').val('');
    $('#precio').val('');
    $('#peso').val('');
}); });
```

My controller

```
public function getCreate()
{
    $client_options = DB::table('cliente_proveedores')->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->where('proveedor', '=', 1)->where('activo', '=', 1)->lists('nombre','id');
    $tipos_ganados = DB::table('tipos_ganados')->orderBy('tipo', 'asc')->where('activo', '=', 1)->lists('tipo','id');
    $razas = DB::table('razas')->orderBy('raza', 'asc')->where('activo', '=', 1)->lists('raza','id');
    return View::make('compras.create', array('client_options' => $client_options, 'tipos_ganados' => $tipos_ganados, 'razas' => $razas));
}


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $compra = new Compra;
    $compra->fecha = Input::get('fecha');
    $compra->num_factura = Input::get('num_factura');
    $compra->id_proveedor = Input::get('proveedor');
    $compra->nombre_vendedor = Input::get('nombre_vendedor');
    $compra->total = Input::get('total');
    $compra->descuento = Input::get('desc');
    $compra->itbms = Input::get('itbms');
    $compra->total_bruto = Input::get('total_bruto');
    if($compra->save()){
        $detalle = new DetalleCompra();
        $detalle->id_compras = Compra::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $detalle->id_ganado = Input::get('num_factura');
        $detalle->precio_kilo = Input::get('data-precio');
        $detalle->peso = Input::get('data-peso');
        $detalle->precio_bruto = Input::get('data-monto');
        $detalle->save();
    }
    if($compra->save()){
        Session::flash('message','Guardado Correctamente');
        Session::flash('class','success');
    }else{
        Session::flash('message','Ha ocurrido un error');
        Session::flash('class','danger');
    }
    return Redirect::to('/compras');
}
```

How i can insert them into a different table?... should i use DB::table('detalle_compras')->insert(); or should replace them with inputs

**PD:** this view is like a shopping cart

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So everything works fine except that it tries to insert it into the wrong table?

Comment: I need to save that data into different table called detalle_compras...

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know, you can send multiple values for the same name by using the `array[]` notation as name attribute. Like shown here:

```
<input type="text" name="test[]" />
<input type="text" name="test[]" />
<input type="text" name="test[]" />
```

If you receive the data on the server it could look like this:

```
array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

(one two three being the values entered in the three input boxes)

**How can we make use of this?**

For every row add input fields with the name and `[]`. For example `name="data-peso[]"`. Make sure those rows are *inside* the form so they actually get submitted with the rest.

Then, in your controller. Use the normal `Input::get()` to receive the values. You can use any of the values, because there should be the same amount of all of them to get the count of rows and loop over every row to extract the values and save the model.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count(Input::get('data-peso')); $i++){
    $detalle = new DetalleCompra();
    $detalle->peso = Input::get('data-peso')[$i];
    $detalle->precio_bruto = Input::get('data-monto')[$i];
    // the other values...
    $detalle->save();
}
```

That should be it already.

Let me finish by saying that there are other ways to accomplish the same thing. For example you could use javascript to process the rows client-side and them using `json` to the server. However with this solution you shouldn't need to change too much of your code to make it work.

Comment: @lukasgeiter is right, I don't think you are explaining everything fully. If the columns exist within this table, you are setting all of the values, and saving, they will show up within db.

I would test that all of the above conditions are correct.

Comment: @user3654532 What do you mean by store every added input? I see your store function and it writes input values to a model and saves it. What about it is not working?

Comment: On my view i should do this: Store Fecha, No factura, proveedor, persona de contacto, total, descuento, itbms, total bruto into a table called compras ( This works fine with the controller) and my model called "Compra" with protected $table = 'compras.'
2. My problem is i should store into other table called "detalle_compras" every added row with the values: sexo, color, raza, tipo , precio x kg , peso, monto and id_compra from "compras". But i dont know how to save this.

Comment: @user3654532 do you want to save every row when it's added or all rows at once?

Comment: @lukasgeiter yes, all rows at once

Comment: @user3654532 ok, last question. do you send the form data via ajax or normal form submit?

Comment: @user3654532 I completely rewrote my answer. Take a look